# processing multiple lines sliding window

Tags: bash, xargs

The headline a generalization of what I want.
Specific problem: given some command that outputs multiple timestamps, e.g:

```
$ cat timestamps | sort -n
1508349271820
1508349271821
1508349425222
1508349425223
1508349454218
1508349476419
1508349500018
1508349500020
1508349698820
1508349698822
1508350047721
1508350047724
1508351635621
1508351635623
1508351699618
1508351699620
1508351699621
1508351699622
1508351699623
1508352230120
1508352230123
1508352230124
1508352230125
1508352232219
1508352232220
1508352364919
1508352364920
1508352387618
1508352387619
```

I want to compute each 2 diff.
I ended up doing something like:

```
$ wc -l timestamps
29

cat <(sort -n timestamps | head -28) <(sort -n timestamps | tail -28) | sort -n | xargs -n 2 sh 'calc $2 - $1' sh
1
153401
1
28995
22201
23599
2
198800
2
348899
3
1587897
2
63995
2
1
1
1
530497
3
1
1
2094
1
132699
1
22698
1
```

So I managed to get by, but there's must be an easier way.
The generalization is: given an output with multiple lines, how can I compute a sliding window of `x` args at once, with `y` args step size?

Comment: The specific example is clear, but the generalization is not.  Please clarify what a "sliding window" is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Awk is well suited for this:

```
awk 'NR>1{print $1-last} {last=$1}' timestamps
```

In the above, for each line after the first (`NR>1`), we print the value on the current value, `$1`, minus the value on the previous line, `last`.  Next, we update the value of `last`.

#### Example

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print $1-last} {last=$1}' timestamps
1
153401
1
28995
22201
23599
2
198800
2
348899
3
1587897
2
63995
2
1
1
1
530497
3
1
1
2094
1
132699
1
22698
1
```

#### More complex calculation

The code below starts with the number in the current line, adds  twice the number in the preceding line, and then subtracts three times the number on the line five lines previous:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$1} NR>5{print a[NR]+2*a[NR-1]-3*a[NR-5]}' timestamps
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not an awk expert, so how do I use an external command, like what I did with `calc` using `xargs`? Moreover, this seems like something that is hard to generalize for every number of args and step size. What if I wanted 3 args, with 1 argument shared each time. Like 1,2,3 and then 3,4,5 etc'... Its great for my specific usecase, but I am interested in a more general solution

Comment: @giladhoch As best I can tell from your description (I am not, for example, at all sure what "1 argument shared" really means), awk would be good for all those things.  Separately, if the question that you posed here is not the one that you want answered, you might ask another question that is aimed more directly at what you want.

Comment: also, why would you want to use a long, complicated, and fragile pipeline of commands when you can do the same task far easier in a scripting language like `awk` (or `perl` or `python`, etc).

Comment: Your answer is great. And I upvoted it to show my gratitude. But it doesnt address the generalization I seek. I gave an example of a simple (real life) use case to illustrate the problem. May be the bottom line question was "swallowed" in the example description. Bottom line, can awk (or other util) can process multiple arguments in a sliding window? And by sliding window I do mean not with some arbitrary size, but easily configurable. Sorry for not being very clear in the question. How do you proposed I edit it?

Comment: Because awk includes a variety of math functions and it supports _both_ variables _and_ arrays, including _multi-dimensional_ arrays, it can be used to implement some complex calculations, including, I expect, a good number of 'sliding window' computations.

Comment: @cas That's exactly my point. These sort of tasks can be easily done in a scripting language. But it sounds to me like it might be doable in a single command like `xargs`.
@John1024 thanks. `awk` is a powerful tool. as said before I am not an expert. Maybe it is the best option. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer.

Comment: I think what you are meaning by "sliding window" can be achieved using the modulo operator (`%`) instead of just subtracting the previous line from the current line.  e.g. use `NR % 3` to check for every third line.  I'm not sure exactly what you want to do with every group of 3 lines so I can't give a more useful example.

Comment: @giladhoch I just added an example of a more complex calculation implementing my interpretation of a "sliding window."

Comment: Thanks @John1024 & cas . This does seem to answer my needs :)

Comment: @giladhoch Apologies if I was slow to understand what you wanted.

Comment: @giladhoch re: "exactly my point" - some tools are better/more-appropriate than others for particular tasks.  You can dig a hole with your bare hands if you really want to, but it would be a lot easier and faster with a pickaxe and shovel.

Answer (score 5):

Install [num-utils](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/), then pipe the file or data to `numinterval`:

```
sort -n timestamps | numinterval
```

Comment: Thats a nifty util. thanks for the pointer :)